# Amazon S3 High CPU Usage

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the PHP SDK of Amazon S3 to upload huge compressed files to the bucket.

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    ...
));

$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3, $file, array(
    'bucket' => $bucket,
    'key'    => $filebase
));

$result = $uploader->upload();
```

However, this is taking a high CPU usage, causing my website to be slow at those times.

Is there any way I can use some kind of "ionice", or control the upload rate, so that it doesn't impact the performance with my users?

Comment: Uploading files requires that a SHA-256 hashes of the file parts be calculated as part of request signing, so high CPU utilization could be expected... and, of course, for "huge" files, there would be more of it.  How huge is "huge?"

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot. Well, one file is 42GB, the other is 90GB. Other files are significantly smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS provides stream wrapper, you can register that with S3 Client. Stream wrapper sends data in chunks and you can also control chunk size.

```
// Register the stream wrapper from an S3Client object
$client->registerStreamWrapper();
```

You can upload larger files by streaming data using fopen() and a "w", "x", or "a" stream access mode. The Amazon S3 stream wrapper does not support simultaneous read and write streams (e.g. "r+", "w+", etc). This is because the HTTP protocol does not allow simultaneous reading and writing.

```
$read = fopen('<YOUR FILE>', 'r');
$stream = fopen('s3://bucket/key', 'w');
 while (!feof($read)) {
    // Read 1024 bytes from the stream
    $content = fread($read, 1024);
    fwrite($stream, $content);
}
fclose($read);
fclose($stream);
```

There might be some other pre-built packages for PHP which do stream upload to S3. I can only think of [Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/recipes/).

Complete Documentation for AWS Stream Wrapper is provided [Here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [MultipartUploader](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html) doing heavy lifting and consume much resources (CPU, network). If upload functionality is required/desired I would consider to move it to *spot instances*. They are cheap and designed for this type of jobs (spin-up, do some heavy task, terminate).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to work in a `sleep($seconds);` into the uploading script. Then set it to sleep at an interval. That way the script will take longer however. Especially with large files.

Comment: Hi. I already have a "sleep()" in the loop that keeps re-trying from where it stopped (because there are timeouts for big files). However, I can't put a sleep while it is uploading the file, which is where it takes high CPU.